# How can I open a new page by id using PHP and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table (mysql):
Optional table caption.

```html
<table class="table"> <caption>myTable</caption> <thead> <tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th>Username</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <th scope="row">1</th> <td>Mark</td> <td>Otto</td> <td>@mdo</td> </tr> <tr> <th scope="row">2</th> <td>Jacob</td> <td>Thornton</td> <td>@fat</td> </tr> <tr> <th scope="row">3</th> <td>Larry</td> <td>the Bird</td> <td>@twitter</td> </tr> </tbody> </table>
```

I have a persons.php page that pull out all person's name from that table, and showing like this:

```html
<div>
    <p>Name: Mark Otto <a href="#">View</a></p>
  <p>Name: Jacob Thornton <a href="#">View</a></p>
  <p>Name: Larry the Bird <a href="#">View</butaon></p>
 </div>
```

And I have a detailed.php that shows person's username, like this:

```html
<div>
  <p>ID: ?</p>
  <p>First name: ?</p>
  <p>Last name: ?</p>
  <p>User name: ?</p>
 </div>
```

My question is that how to get detailed.php page by id when click the 'View' link?

Sorry, I am learning PHP, my point is when click the view link, what is the way to get the detailed.php displayed by the ID. I know how to get data displayed while using php+mysql, but I don't know how to perform the click action and direct to detailed.php page that showing info by id.

Thanks!

Comment: Pass the db entry id via `$_GET`, then query with a `WHERE` clause using the id.

Comment: Make view a link with the href attribute equal to detailed.php?id={the user ID}.  Links look a lot better than buttons for navigation IMO

Comment: Do you use a query to get the data for `detailed.php`? If so, can you not just use the same query on `persons.php`?

Comment: Thanks for advice!

Comment: The way is shown in my answer : you send the ID as part of the URL, then detailed.php receives the value from $_GET. The `<a` performs the click action and directs to detailed.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `<button` by `<a href`. In "persons.php" you will need to echo the ID in the `<a href`, later, in "detailed.php", you get the value as `$_GET[ "id" ]`:

**persons.php**

```
  <div>
    Name: Larry the Bird <a href="detailed.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">View</a>
```

**detailed.php**

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_GET[ "id" ] ) )
   echo "<p>ID: " . $_GET[ "id" ] . "</p>";
?>
```

Comment: @LesterX, what exactly are you looking for? Do you really want to use a button?

Comment: No, It's not necessary to use a button. I guess your answer is closer to my question! thanks a lot

Comment: I will try it later .

Answer (score 1):

Try this! put your query instead of'$yourquery'

#### persons.php

```
<?php
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th># </th>
        <th>Name</th> 
        <th>Action</th> 
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($yourquery))
    {
    ?>
    <tr> 
      <td>Name : <?=$row['name']?>  <?=$row['lastname']?></td> 
      <form method="GET" action="detailed.php">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?=$row['id']?>" name="id" />
            <td><button type="submit">View</button></td>
      </form>
    </tr> 
  <?php
    }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```