# fill data into form from landing page in HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I created following html form

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" >
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
<input type="text" name="age" id="age">
<input type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I want to input data in this form from  the landing page (landing page will display all previously entered record)

[Actual form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvfnX.jpg)
[landing page from where i want o add data into form by clicking Add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNpKr.jpg)

Can i do it with java script or any other method ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I open a new page by id using PHP and mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010138/how-can-i-open-a-new-page-by-id-using-php-and-mysql)

Comment: i want to autofil my form from another page(landing page) by clicking on ADD data. I think it will be done by java script onclick event. but i dont knew how ??

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Form</title>
  <script>
    // Retrieve and populate the form fields with data from localStorage
    window.onload = function() {
      var storedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formData'));
      if (storedData) {
        document.getElementById('name1').value = storedData.name1;
        document.getElementById('lastname').value = storedData.lastname;
        document.getElementById('age').value = storedData.age;
      }
    };

    // Save the form data to localStorage
    function saveFormData() {
      var name1 = document.getElementById('name1').value;
      var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
      var age = document.getElementById('age').value;

      var formData = {
        name1: name1,
        lastname: lastname,
        age: age
      };

      localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(formData));

      alert('Form data saved!');
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1">
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
    <input type="text" name="age" id="age">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="saveFormData()">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks alot for your answer. I want that data  should be load from another page (data dispaly from mysql table on that page)

Answer (score 0):

so let's assume your first page is on this url, https://example.com/list
and then the form page is on https://example.com/form

in the list page you must path values to the form page so in the table you will have something like this

```
<tr>
  ....
  <td><a href="/form">add</a></td>
</tr>
```

now we have multiple ways to achieve what you want:

- you can pass an identifier from the record like an id so in that case the url will look something like this `<a href="/form?id=123">add</a>` or if you have routing handler and you can catch the path parameters it can be `<a href="/form/123">add</a>` and then in the form page you can catch this identifier and make an ajax to get user info and then update the value of the inputs using JS based on the response on ajax
- you can pass all the info you need in the url so in that case the url will look like this `<a href="/form?name1=name1&lastname=last&age=49">add</a>` and in this case you don't need an ajax on the form page since you already have all the data in the request

Comment: thanks for your useful answer. The problem is the page from where i want to add value is dynamic page which display value from mysql database. How can i handle this in that case ????

Comment: How are you displaying the records from mysql, can you share this part, so we can understand more ?